# How to structure DB for performant, customizable aggregations?

Tags: database, postgresql, analytics

I am planning to setup a database for some rudimentary aggregations. The plan is to provide queries like `SELECT SUM(energy) WHERE`... to our users.

`energy` is a plain numerical field. The `WHERE` clause is more interesting, because we expose some (limited) customizability to the user, basically just `AND`ing some fields for equality. Like `A=3`, `A=3 AND B=92`, etc.

I'm no DBA, but my performance sense is tingling. As it stands, I'm anticipating a load of `O(user * record)` on the database, should the queries be fired off all at once. Is there a way to optimize this better?

If the `WHERE` condition were fixed, then we could simply provide a view or otherwise precalculate and cache the sum. Unfortunately, in this case, we will be providing limited ability to customize the `WHERE` expression, basically offering some fields for the users to `AND` at will.

Looks to me like each of these aggregation queries would traverse basically the whole table, or significant subsections of the table, one traversal per user query. Does that make sense?

What are some ways to optimize for this kind of workflow? Should I just shard over many of my fields? I'm considering how many replicas to use, though I am unsure if `|replicas|` would be able to outpace growth of users or data, due to the data totality of the aggregation queries.

In terms of low-level performance, would it make sense to structure these queries as `SELECT SUM(energy)>N WHERE`..., and hope that PostgreSQL is smart enough to terminate early when the subtotal is found to already exceed the threshold `N`?

Finally, would a NoSQL or TSDB offer advantages for this workflow, or would their performance be comparable to a SQL database?

**Update**

Since most of these queries will be run on a schedule, I think I will stagger them to spread the load throughout the day. But I'm still keen on finding better ways to optimize the tables for this load, should a bunch of active users suddenly submit aggregation queries all at once.

Comment: How many rows are we talking about? Typically you scale a relational database by increasing I/O throughput, i.e. using high-end SSDs rather than desktop HDDs. More memory usually helps as well as do clever indexing strategies.

Comment: Do you _know_ you have a problem?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name around 10M rows currently, with growth planned. Yes, RAM>SSD>HDD. In this case, I'm concerned about the schema and query efficiency more than the hardware.

Comment: 10 million rows is nothing with today's hardware (especially with all the performance improvements introduced in Postgres 11). With a proper data model (possibly de-normalized as usually done for data warehouse environments) even 100 million rows won't be a problem. But without more details (e.g. the **actual** queries or at least table definitions) this is impossible to answer.

Comment: Without a schema or specific sample queries, it looks like your where clause can be optimized by indexing. This should make your queries very fast for most cases - is that not your expectation?